# Error when using SqlDataSource and Parameters

Tags: c#, sql, c#-4.0

I get the following error when trying to use the SelectCommand of an SqlDataSource and Gridview.  I feel like what I have should work, but I get this error; I suspect that I'm close but am overlooking something:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name '@tbl'. 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() 
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) 
at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) 
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) 
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) 
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable) 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) 
at System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() 
at Test.BindData() in C:\Dev\Test.aspx.cs:line 45
```

ASPX:

```
   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTable" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"/>

   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDS" runat="server" SelectCommand="Select * From [@tbl]">
       <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlTable" Name="tbl" PropertyName="SelectedItem.Text" />
       </SelectParameters>
   </asp:SqlDataSource>

   <asp:GridView
    ID="grd"
    CssClass="auto"
    runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="sqlDS"
    AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true"
    AutoGenerateEditButton="true" />
```

Code:

```
sqlDS.ConnectionString = "valid connection string";
grd.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not valid SQL, that is your problem. I am not sure what you are trying to get, but you cannot pass a parameter in that will act as a table. Your query needs to select from a database, and you can use the parameter for filtering or selecting. You just cannot use it as a table itself. Maybe you are looking for something more like this?

```
Select ID From tablename where columnname = '@tbl'
```

Comment: GAAAAHAH; hours wasted. Thank You!